# Calls from Android to Salesforce

Tags: android, salesforce, calllog

Is there any way to log incoming and outgoing calls from my Android and move them into Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [CallLogs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html) content provider on Android to access the call log on the device, and you can then take that data and send it to Salesforce via their [REST api](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm), either to a custom object you define, or to the standard object Task, so that it'll appear in the activity history of the related data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Salesforce Call Tracker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.akvelon.salesforce.atracker) app to log your calls from Android into salesforce as activities. 
looks like it is exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rest API, specially Salesforce Mobile SDK that work with it. I used it in a personal project and it works. You just have to allow access to your mobile app in SalesForce   by creating a remote access in the setup of your SalesForce account.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK